# virtualbox fails after kernel update

Tags: kernel, virtualbox

I have ubuntu 16 LTS. Virtualbox could run, but I have removed it. After some time, I update kernel to 4.7.2. Installing Virtualbox again but it does not boot the guest system. It shows this message:

> Kernel drive not installed rc=1908

It tells me to rin /sbin/vboxconfig, but the script fails:

> vboxdrv.sh: Building VirtualBox kernel modules. vboxdrv.sh: failed:
>   Look at /var/log/vbox-install.log to find out what went wrong.
>
> There were problems setting up VirtualBox.  To re-start the set-up
>   process, run   /sbin/vboxconfig as root.

This is the log file:

http://pastebin.com/1eBGCZUM

What should I do to make Virtualbox work again?

Thanks.

Comment: VBox version? You may need the latest release to support installing on a brand new host kernel.

Comment: I have tried the apt-ger version, and also the deb file from Virtualbox website. Both does not work after kernel update.

Answer (score 5):

Based on [a discussion on Ubuntu Forums](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2055886), the following worked for me when I upgraded kernel in Ubuntu:

```
$ sudo dpkg-reconfigure virtualbox-dkms && sudo dpkg-reconfigure virtualbox && \
    sudo modprobe vboxdrv
```

Comment: I really wish I could make that automated after an update somehow. This is the answer that I keep coming back to and that works.

Comment: Works fine on Ubuntu and Debian without rebooting.

Answer (score 1):

I would uninstall and then re-install VirtualBox:

```
sudo apt purge virtualbox*
wget http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/5.1.4/virtualbox-5.1_5.1.4-110228~Ubuntu~xenial_amd64.deb
sudo dpkg -i virtualbox-5.1_5.1.4-110228~Ubuntu~xenial_amd64.deb
```

Your guests will not be deleted and should appear when you open VirtualBox. You may have problems with the guest network interfaces after re-installing VirtualBox. If you do, just disable the network interface, start the guest, stop the guest, then re-enable the network interface.

Comment: after typing in dpkg, during the installation, it shows: "
vboxdrv.sh: failed: Look at /var/log/vbox-install.log to find out what went wrong.

There were problems setting up VirtualBox.  To re-start the set-up process, run
  /sbin/vboxconfig
as root."

Comment: Have you made sure no guests are running? Perhaps try uninstalling using the Software Centre. If that fails, you could always try to force the uninstall: `sudo apt-get --force-yes remove virtualbox-5.1`

Comment: Sorry, just re-read your comment - was the uninstall successful? Is it just the re-installation you're having problems with? Have you looked at /var/log/vbox-install.log? What does it say in vbox-install.log?

Comment: The other thing you could try is installing using: `sudo apt install virtualbox-5.1`

Answer (score 1):

On Fedora, I've been doing a `/usr/sbin/vboxconfig` after kernel updates, it seems to do a good job of rebuilding the kernel drivers after kernel updates.

Comment: it is likely a conflict between old script and new headers as some commands are obsoleted.

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is issue:

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure virtualbox-5.1
```

Once you do you will get the setup message that it needs to create a system users group.  Just hit enter and it will drop back to terminal and you will see a one liner stating the group already exists and a blank line below that.  The module rebuild process is hidden behind this blank line.  Wait until an interactive prompt returns (only takes a minute or 2).  Then you will be good to go.  No need to re-install the program man that's overkill.

**Also for other Host Linux OSes (or if you like to see more info on Ubuntu) the following command is all you need on any Linux host:**

```
 /sbin/rcvboxdrv setup
```

This works the same as the older /etc/init.d/vboxdrv setup  they have just changed the name.

Answer (score 0):

None of the above worked when it tried the various suggested remedies. However, the problem was fixed by upgrading Ubuntu 16.04 to Ubuntu 18.04 using the software updater.